# How to use Hibernate lazy loading and reactive streams?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, reactive-streams, micronaut-data

I am currently building a REST service with Micronaut Data. I have defined two JPA entities, bounded by a bidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship, and lazy loading.

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ScoringEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "scoring", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ContributionEntity> contributions;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ContributionEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private ScoringEntity scoring;
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface ScoringRepository extends GenericRepository<ScoringEntity, String> {

    Page<ScoringEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

In the controller, I return a `Mono` which is set to call the repository, then perform a mapping to a DTO (`Scoring`).

```java
@Get
public Mono<Page<Scoring>> getScoring(Pageable pageable) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> scoringRepository.findAll(pageable))
        .map(scoringEntities -> scoringEntities.map(scoringMapper::mapScoring));
}
```

Everything works fine in the `findAll()` method, but things go south when the mapper
tries to access the contributions set :

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ScoringEntity.contributions, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

While I understand why this happens (the transaction probably ends with the repository method), I can't find a satisfying solution. Setting the relationship to eager loading works, but it
significantly decreases performance (and I've read [elsewhere](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) it would be a code smell, which I tend to believe).

Besides I can't imagine that reactive streams be incompatible with hibernate and lazy loading.

What would be the best practice in this situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Add `@Join("contributions")` annotation to your repository method
2. Add `@EntityGraph ...` annotation to your repository method
3. Do fetching and mapping in one method annotated `@ReadOnly` or `@Transactional` so the session is open when the mapper is called

In this case, having reactive streams doesn't make much sense. Just return `Page` from the controller annotated `@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)`.

Comment: I thought it was not recommended to perform blocking IO operations in the event loop.

Comment: Correct, my answer was missing that the controller needs to be annotated with `@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)`.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping the association as `EAGER` is usually a code smell. But if you have situations where you always need to load an association,  you can do it via a query.

Instead of `findAll`, you would call:

```
@Repository
public interface ScoringRepository extends GenericRepository<ScoringEntity, String> {

    @Query("select se from ScoringEntity se left fetch join se.contributions")
    Page<ScoringEntity> findScoringWithContributions(Pageable pageable);

}
```

> Besides I can't imagine that reactive streams be incompatible with hibernate and lazy loading.

In this case the problem is that you are trying to lazy load the association after the session has been closed.